# mclapply warnings: scheduled cores ... did not deliver results, all values of the jobs will be affected

Tags: r, optimization, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach, doparallel

I am trying to optimize my R code using "foreach" and "doParallel" package. My code is running in the serial version without any warnings and errors, but I get this error while using %dopar%: In mclapply(argsList, FUN, mc.preschedule = preschedule, mc.set.seed = set.seed,:scheduled cores ... did not deliver results, all values of the jobs will be affected.
Can you please let me know if you have any suggestions to solve this issue?

```
registerDoParallel(cores=40)
registerDoRNG(123)

foreach(i = 1:1000,.combine='+') %dopar% {
   f(...)
} -> pf
```

Comment: First of all please check out `?registerDoParallel` usage. The message is surprising as mclapply is a multicore and %dopar% is a multisession tool. Hard to debug without the function definition and your system specification (Mac or Windows). Might be the problem of strangely set `registerDoParallel`.

Comment: @polkas I changed it to no_of_cores = detectCores()
no_of_cores
cl = makeCluster(no_of_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)! I did not get the previous error, but this time I got this error:"slurmstepd: error: Detected 1 oom-kill event(s) in step 506736.batch cgroup. Some of your processes may have been killed by the cgroup out-of-memory handler." which is related to the remote cluster that I am working on! I run my code on computecanada cluster (Linux).

Comment: Hi, 

Can you give an example of the tasks that you are running? For me it looks like RAM issues - I recently ran into this problem with our ABACUS 2.0 running on 250 gb RAM. The `mclapply` errors are usually predictable.

Comment: "Detected 1 oom-kill event(s) in step 506736.batch cgroup" means that the Slurm scheduler terminated your job because it consumed more memory than you asked for.  So, specify a large amount via `--mem=...` when you submit the job.